# Richfaces Plug'n'Skin - how to provide images?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, skinning

I'm trying to build a custom richfaces skin by the `Plug'n'Skin` feature. I've build the project with maven. (like its mentioned in the reference guide)

I've tried to use the `xcss`wich isn't supplied to my app - everything looks like default. So I switched back to normal css in my `tab-panel.xcss`. This works: Styles are applied but one issue which I can't resolve:

How do I provide images to my css classes?

Example of my `tab-panel.css`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:template xmlns:f="http://jsf.exadel.com/template"
xmlns:u="http://jsf.exadel.com/template/util"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<f:verbatim>
<![CDATA[
    .rich-tab-active {
        background-image:url(register_active_bg.png);
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#000000;
        border-top:1px solid #c8c8c8;
    }
    .rich-tab-bottom-line {
    }
    .rich-tab-disabled, .rich-tab-inactive {
        background-image:url(register_bg.png);
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        color:#969696;
    }
    .rich-tab-header {
        width:160px;
        height:45px;
        line-height:43px;
        font-size:12px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .rich-tabhdr-cell-active {
    }
    .rich-tabhdr-cell-disabled {
    }
    .rich-tabhdr-cell-inactive {
    }
    .rich-tabhdr-side-border {
    }
    .rich-tabhdr-side-cell {
    }
    .rich-tabpanel {
        width:818px;
    }
    .rich-tabpanel-content {
    }
    .rich-tabpanel-content-position {
    }
]]>
</f:verbatim>
</f:template>
```

I've tried to register the image in my `resource-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource-config>
    <resource>
        <name>register_bg.png</name>
        <path>de/bc/richfaces/images/register_bg.png</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>register_active_bg.png</name>
        <path>de/bc/richfaces/images/register_bg.png</path>
    </resource>
</resource-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After recreating the skin project with a baseskin it worked out for me like in my question, I post it here once again for more clarity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource-config>
    <resource>
        <name>register_bg.png</name>
        <path>de/bc/richfaces/images/register_bg.png</path>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>register_active_bg.png</name>
        <path>de/bc/richfaces/images/register_bg.png</path>
    </resource>
</resource-config>
```